# Pandas Lambda expression to search substring not working for numeric pincode

Tags: pandas

I have 4 compete address in column and CITY PICODE in different column of same datatframe, below expression returns correct result for CITY but not for Pincode which is 6 digit number.

ConAddress is the concatenation of all 5 client address columns

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_excel('Rural_Data.xlsx')

df['ConAddress'] = df['CLIENT_ADDRESS_1'].astype(str)+' '+df['CLIENT_ADDRESS_2'].astype(str)+' '+df['CLIENT_ADDRESS_3'].astype(str)+' '+df['CLIENT_ADDRESS_4'].astype(str)+' '+df['CLIENT_ADDRESS_5'].astype(str)
# filling na as if blank cell will be there in the address columns mentioned above it will find the match
df.update(df[['VILLAGENAME','TALUKANAME','DISTRICTNAME','PINCODENEW']].fillna('--'))
df_given_columns =df[['VILLAGENAME','TALUKANAME','DISTRICTNAME','PINCODENEW']]

print(df['PINCODENEW'].dtype)
for gcol in list(df_given_columns.columns.values):
    result_column_name= str(gcol)[:3]
    df[gcol]=df[gcol].astype(str)
    # df[result_column_name] = df.apply(lambda x: x[gcol] in x['ConAddress'], axis=1).astype(int)
    df[result_column_name] = (df.apply(lambda x: str(x[gcol]) in x['ConAddress'], axis=1)).astype(int)
df_result_columns = df[['VIL','TAL','DIS','PIN']]
print(df_result_columns['PIN'].head())
df.to_csv('outputs.csv')
```

Sample Data

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lusfgHHX_qmqYuaw0xexDF2hovkcU8py/view?usp=sharing

```
ConAddress                                          DISTRICTNAME  PINCODENEW
AP MOHI MANTAL MANDIST SATARA 415508 MAHA               SATARA      415508
AP BHAGAT MALA VADIYERAYBAG SATARA SATARA 415305        SATARA      415305
AT POST ,NHAVI,TAL-INDAPUR PUNE MAHARASHTRA             PUNE    
AT POST ,NHAVI,TAL-INDAPUR PUNE MAHARASHTRA             Delhi
```

Comment: Please add examples of your input data and expected output.

Comment: @ScootCork added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had a look on your data , column has that green symbol comes in excel for format changing.
Similar issue I had  in searching mobile number change below lines just before your for loop it hope it will work fine.

```
df['PINCODENEW'] = df['PINCODENEW'].astype(int, errors='ignore')
df['PINCODENEW'] = df['PINCODENEW'].astype(str).replace('\.0','', regex=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert value to string by `str`:

```
df['Result'] = (df.apply(lambda x: str(x['PINCODENEW']) in x['ConAddress'], axis=1)
                  .astype(int))
```

Comment: I had converted in str before applying

Comment: @AditiPatil - What is `print (df['PINCODENEW'].dtype)` before `df['Result'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['PINCODENEW'] in x['ConAddress'], axis=1).astype(int)` ?

Comment: print(df['PINCODENEW'].dtype) is object

Comment: @AditiPatil - thanks, there are not some values like `415508.0` ?

Comment: @AditiPatil - Ok, just requsted permission

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217012/discussion-between-aditi-patil-and-jezrael).